# How do we create the partitions in hive with the Spaces?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, hadoop-partitioning

We want to create the partitions in hive table, but the partition name have some spaces. So it cant create the partitions. Currently we are using the java.
 We tried to escape the space but all are throwing exception.

```
URL -s3n://comp-data-bckp/data/datav/sample_test/sample_test_inner/2016-06-27/hive/warehouse/datav/sample_test_inner/platform=SONY PS3

HiveConf hiveConf= new HiveConf();
    hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, URL);
    hiveConf.setIntVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORE_CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT, 60);
    CliSessionState css = new CliSessionState(hiveConf);
    css.in = System.in;
    css.out = null;
    css.err = null;
    css.setIsSilent(true);

    SessionState.start(css);
    CliDriver cli = new CliDriver();
    int response = cli.processLine(statements);

    SessionState s = SessionState.get();
    if (s != null && s.out != null && s.out != System.out)
    {
        s.out.close();
    }
    return response;


    java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 126: s3n://comp-data-bckp/data/datav/sample_test/sample_test_inner/2016-06-27/hive/warehouse/datav/sample_test_inner/platform=SONY PS3
```

When we try to escape the space character with below options  system still throws the above error.

```
-   \\                               (eg. S3n://…./ platform=SONY\\ PS3)

-   %20                        (eg. S3n://…./ platform=SONY%20PS3)

-   +                             (eg. S3n://…./ platform=SONY+PS3)
```

Please assist if there are any options to escape it and provide inputs for proceeding  further.

Comment: Try again wit %20 and make sure there are no other invalid characters present.

Comment: @Paul, Thank for your reply. I tried the below three options as \\, %20 and +.

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham,Did you resolve it or it's still pending.I am also facing this issue.Suggest me if you have any idea.

Comment: @VishwanathSharma - No not yet resolved.